# Cannot signal semaphore with Firebase observeEventType - what gives?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

I am using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to read/write data to a remote server.

My objective is to write a routine that also takes a callback function. Heres what the routine should accomplish:

1. Write some data to Firebase (this works fine)
2. Observe for changes on above written data
3. If change occurs call callback with success
4. If a timeout is triggered, call callback with failure

Im unable to figure out why steps 2-4 are failing for me. Below is a snippet of the code

Here's whats going on in the code:

1. It sets up a GCD semaphore
2. It writes some data to the root firebase URL - specifically it adds a user called joe. This works fine. I can see the data written from [Vulcan](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-09-30-vulcan.html)
3. it sets up a reference to Joe's node and watches for events on childAdded for Joe. [Here is the API reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/observeEventType:withBlock:)
4. Upon successfully getting an event it signals the semaphore, which should call the callback with message "Success"
5. Instead I see the "timeout" message. Strangely though the observer does print out the newly added key:value pair, which is doubly confusing!

Whats going on here? Am I using semaphores incorrectly? Or am i using Firebase's API incorrectly?

typealias completionfoo = (gid:String) -> Void

```
func setStateReady(somestr: String, callfoo: completionfoo) {
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)        

var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/")
var joe = ["state" : "READY", "msg" : somestr]
var usersRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users")
var users = ["joe": joe]
usersRef.setValue(users)

var joeref = Firebase(url: "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/users/joe/")

// Read data and react to changes

joeref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
    snapshot in
    print(snapshot.key)
    print(snapshot.value)
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
})

let timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(30 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

if dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, timeout) != 0 {
    joeref.removeAllObservers()
    callfoo(gid: "timeout")
} else {
    joeref.removeAllObservers()
    callfoo(gid: "success")
}
}
override func viewDidLoad() {    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setStateReady("hi i am joe") { (gid) -> Void in
        print(gid)
    }
```